# Angular2 - Stand alone components

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrapping, angular-cli

Can I do a partial bootstrap of all the components created so that we can use any of the components at a point of time?

For eg, if i have 5 components which has been bootstrapped in the app.module, is there any provision of defining only two of them in index.html instead of defining all the five components?